# Java JAX-WS xs:dateTime with format UTC and Local

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws

I'm programming a web service with JAX-WS. I have 2 date fields but they are with different formats. example

`<DateTimeLocal>2014-06-03T14:46:48-05:00</DateTimeLocal><!--I need the format: 2014-06-03T14:46:48 -->`

`<DateTimeUTC>2014-06-03T14:46:48-05:00</DateTimeUTC><!--I need the format: 2015-07-23T00:00:00Z -->`

My class:

```
public class Test implements Serializable {    
    private Date dateTimeLocal;
    private Date dateTimeUTC;

    @XmlElement(name="DateTimeLocal")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    public Date getDateTimeLocal() {
        return dateTimeLocal;
    }

    public void setDateTimeLocal(Date dateTimeLocal) {
        this.dateTimeLocal = dateTimeLocal;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="DateTimeUTC")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    public Date getDateTimeUTC() {
        return dateTimeUTC;
    }

    public void setDateTimeUTC(Date dateTimeUTC) {
        this.dateTimeUTC = dateTimeUTC;
    }                    
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming based on the field names what you are really saying is you need the field `dateTimeLocal` to return the `xs:dateTime` representing local time of the service provider, but you want `dateTimeUTC` to represent the `xs:dateTime` of GMT or UTC.  These aren't really formats (like Java `DateFormat`) but rather time zone representations.

That said, here is at least one way to do this: by using `java.util.Calendar` and its ability to reflect relative time at a given `java.util.TimeZone`:

```
package org.example.sampleservice;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Test implements Serializable {

    private Date dateTimeLocal;
    private Calendar dateTimeUTC;

    @XmlElement(name="DateTimeLocal")
    public Date getDateTimeLocal() {
        return dateTimeLocal;
    }

    public void setDateTimeLocal(Date dateTimeLocal) {
        this.dateTimeLocal = dateTimeLocal;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="DateTimeUTC")
    public Calendar getDateTimeUTC() {
        return dateTimeUTC;
    }

    public void setDateTimeUTC(Calendar dateTimeUTC) {
        this.dateTimeUTC = dateTimeUTC;
    }
}
```

Then, in your service implementation (where `Test` is populated):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
...    
Test result = new Test();
result.setDateTimeLocal(new Date());
Calendar zuluTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
result.setDateTimeUTC(zuluTime);
```

Running this around 9:47 PM eastern US time, I get:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getTestResponse xmlns:ns2="http://sampleservice.example.org/">
         <return>
            <DateTimeLocal>2016-12-07T21:47:04.988-05:00</DateTimeLocal>
            <DateTimeUTC>2016-12-08T02:47:04.988Z</DateTimeUTC>
         </return>
      </ns2:getTestResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Since `America/New_York` time is GMT minus 5 hours,

`<DateTimeLocal>2016-12-07T21:47:04.988-05:00</DateTimeLocal>`

depicts December 7 9:47 PM whereas

`<DateTimeUTC>2016-12-08T02:47:04.988Z</DateTimeUTC>`

depicts it is actually December 8, 2:47 AM in Greenwich Mean Time (UTC or Zulu time).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scott, the example is correct by my problem is that i am use JAXWS, then when i test the ws the date is formatted by local time zone(jvm)  example:

`<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:Response xmlns:ns2="http://......">
            <CreateDateTime>2014-06-03T14:46:48-05:00</CreateDateTime>
            <LastModifiedDateTimeUTC>2014-06-13T21:09:21Z</LastModifiedDateTimeUTC>

        </ns2:Response>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>`

Actuality i am use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter

```
public class Test implements Serializable {
    private DateTime dateTimeLocal
    private DateTime dateTimeUTC

    @XmlElement(name="DateTimeLocal")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    public DateTime getDateTimeLocal() {
        return dateTimeLocal;
    }   
    public void setDateTimeLocal(DateTime dateTimeLocal) {
        this.dateTimeLocal = dateTimeLocal;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="DateTimeUTC")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    public DateTime getDateTimeUTC() {
        return dateTimeUTC;
    }
    public void setDateTimeUTC(DateTime dateTimeUTC) {
        this.dateTimeUTC = dateTimeUTC;
    }
}

public class DateTimeUTCAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));

    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
         return formatter.parseDateTime(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(DateTime v) throws Exception {
        return formatter.print(v);
    }
}
```